# How to get the equivalent of int list from a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new in programming and I am trying to get the equivalent of my list manually from a base64 dict that I created without using base64 module but I don't know how to do it.

```
base64tbl ={0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 3:'D', 4:'E', 5:'F', 6:'G', 7:'H', 8:'I', 9:'J',
            10:'K', 11:'L', 12:'M', 13:'N', 14:'O', 15:'P',16:'Q', 17:'R',18:'S', 19:'T',
            20:'U', 21:'V', 22:'W', 23:'X', 24:'Y' ,25:'Z' ,26:'a', 27:'b', 28:'c', 29:'d',
            30:'e', 31:'f', 32:'g', 33:'h', 34:'i' ,35:'j' ,36:'k', 37:'l', 38:'m', 39:'n',
            40:'o', 41:'p', 42:'q', 43:'r', 44:'s' ,45:'t' ,46:'u', 47:'v', 48:'w', 49:'x',
            50:'y', 51:'z', 52:'0', 53:'1', 54:'2' ,55:'3' ,56:'4', 57:'5', 58:'6', 59:'7',
            60:'8', 61:'9', 62:'+', 63:'/'}

lists:  [7, 4, 11, 11, 14]
```

The output should be: HELLO

Comment: `''.join([base64tbl[x] for x in lists])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator comprehension.

```py
print("".join(base64tbl[c] for c in lists))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for to solve the problem

```
chars = []
for i in lists:
    chars.append(base64btl[i])
print("".join(chars))
```